# Awk / Sed - repeating date print

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data line beginning with the date, and then some process stats,

```
Jul 2 04:44:57 root: Memory Snapshot: 1 (init) 3654623 74 13113 (mini_httpd) 234234 115 45 (controld) 34234 57 ...
```

I split the processes onto separate lines thanks to you guys, using

```
sed -rn 's/([0-9]+ (\([a-z._0-9]+\)) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) / \1 \2 \3 \4 \n/gp'
```

What i'd like to do is prepend each line with the date from that line. so i get the below.

```
Jul 2 04:44:57 1 (init) 3654623 74
Jul 2 04:44:57 13113 (mini_httpd) 234234 115
Jul 2 04:44:57 45 (controld) 34234 57
```

Thanks

Andy

Comment: What happens to the `root: Memory Snapshot:` text?  Just throw it away?  Might there be any other text in its place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    date = $1 FS $2 FS $3
    while ( match($0,/[0-9]+ \([^)]+\)( [0-9]+){2}/) ) {
        print date, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Jul 2 04:44:57 1 (init) 3654623 74
Jul 2 04:44:57 13113 (mini_httpd) 234234 115
Jul 2 04:44:57 45 (controld) 34234 57
```

Comment: Note that this appears to work with gawk, but not with non-GNU awk on FreeBSD. I haven't figured out why though. It's something about the RE not finding content in `match()`.

Comment: @ghoti There might be some older, non-POSIX awk version out there that doesn't support RE intervals (e.g. the very inappropriately-named `nawk`) in which case you'd need to write the regexp as `/[0-9]+ \([^)]+\) [0-9]+ [0-9]+/` but you should really just get a newer (POSIX at least) awk - GNU awk if at all possible.

Comment: Whoa. That was indeed it. The BSDs avoid GNU versions of things for political/religious (license) reasons, so their default awk is not GNU. FreeBSD's is based on Brian Kernighan's original "[One True Awk](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/contrib/one-true-awk)". FreeBSD devs has made a few additions to it (POSIX character classes for one), but bounds appear not to have made it. I do most of my awk using gawk anyway, though I try to keep things compatible with the base system when I can. Not sure how I could have missed this though!

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu-awk you can do this:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+ \\([^)]+\\) [0-9]+ [0-9]+' 'NR==1{dt=$1 FS $2 FS $3}
           RT{print dt, RT}' file
```

**Output:**

```
Jul 2 04:44:57 1 (init) 3654623 74
Jul 2 04:44:57 13113 (mini_httpd) 234234 115
Jul 2 04:44:57 45 (controld) 34234 57
```

`-v RS='[0-9]+ \\([^)]+\\) [0-9]+ [0-9]+'` sets input record separator as the given regex and `RT` gives us matched text by that regex inside the awk command.

Answer (score 0):

If your file (line) structure is fixed, you can do positional access instead of regex.  For example

```
$ awk '{for(i=7;i<=NF-3;i+=4) print $1,$2,$3,$i,$(i+1),$(i+2),$(i+3)}' line
```

will give you

```
Jul 2 04:44:57 1 (init) 3654623 74                                                                                                              
Jul 2 04:44:57 13113 (mini_httpd) 234234 115
Jul 2 04:44:57 45 (controld) 34234 57
```